# Muting ads with react-native-google-mobile-ads and Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, ads, google-mobile-ads, react-native-google-mobile-ads

Is there a way to mute react-native-google-mobile-ads ads in Expo?

There is a guide for native apps here for Android https://developers.google.com/admob/android/global-settings?hl=pl and here for iOS https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/global-settings?hl=pl but how to handle it on Expo?